# Why is it necessary to iterate through a NodeList if it is already an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on an assignment that involves using a `for` loop to iterate through a NodeList of all the button tags on an HTML page using the following code:

```
var bns = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for (var i = 0; i < bns.length; i++) {
  bns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("you clicked"); 
  });
}
```

This code works, however, I am struggling to understand why it is necessary to do this, i.e. to put a NodeList into an array in order to access it. Isn't a NodeList already an array?

Comment: I don't see anything like "putting the nodelist in an array" in the code you've given... In fact your code contains no arrays at all...

Comment: No, a NodeList is not an array. It has numbered properties and a `length` property, but it doesn’t inherit from `Array`, so one wouldn’t have a `forEach` property, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. So I gather the `for` loop here is iterating through the NodeList?

Comment: Where are you putting it into an Array? What do you think you do not need to do in the code above?

Comment: @minitech—well, you can do `[].forEach.call(myCollection, callback)`.

Comment: @eabates: Yes, that's exactly what it's doing.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A nodeList is an array-like object.  It is not actually an array.  The ONLY property is has in common with an array is `.length` and array indexing.  It does not have any of the other methods of an array.

But, because it supports array indexing and the `.length` property, you can iterate through it with a `for` loop just like you would with an array.  But, you can't use `.forEach()` on it because that's an actual array method which a `nodeList` object does not have.

The code in your question is not "putting a nodeList into an array" at all.  It is accessing the elements of a `nodeList` object using `.length` and `bns[i]` to access the numeric properties of the nodeList.

You can think of a nodeList object more like this:

```
var myNodeList = {
    length: 3,
    "0": domObj1,
    "1": domObj2,
    "2": domObj3
};
```

In this array-like object, you can do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myNodeList.length; i++) {
    console.log(myNodeList[i]);
}
```

Even though it is not actually an array.  A `nodeList` is actually a form of host object that has been given a limited Javascript interface.

---

FYI, there are times when it is useful to copy a nodeList into an actual array - when you want to make a dynamic nodeList into a static array or when you want to be able to use more Array methods on it.  That can be done like this:

```
var bns = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
// copy the nodeList into an actual array
var myArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(bns);

myArray.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

---

FYI, here's a good section on MDN about [Why is nodeList not an Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Why_is_NodeList_not_an_Array).

And, the `Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList)` conversion requires IE9+.  If you want that supported in older versions of IE, you can use a shim [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Streamlining_cross-browser_behavior).

Comment: Be careful though. Some browsers (e.g. IE 8) do not allow built–in methods to be called with host objects as *this*, so using *slice* to convert to an array will fail.

Comment: `NodeList` also has an `item` method so `myNodeList[i]` could be written as `myNodeList.item(i)` which might be better because it reinforces that this is not an `Array` and returns `null` instead of `undefined` if the index is not found. Great MDN page on this, but beware that the ES6 spread operator doesnt work yet in chrome to expand a `NodeList` to an `Array` due to lack of destructuring support :( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Comment: @pherris - I personally have found no reason to use `.item()` on a `nodeList` over the array indexing.  I'm honestly not even sure why they bothered with that method.  I might hazard a guess that it has to do with internal (in the C++ code where it does not behave like an array) use of the nodeList and they just decided to surface it out to Javascript.

Comment: @RobG - When do we stop providing caveats in answers to things that aren't supported in IE8?  I guess I thought that time had passed already.  Anyway, you are correct.  IE8 is so brain damaged that `Array.prototype.slice.call` can't handle an array-like object.  There is a shim for fixing that issue in any IE < 9 [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Streamlining_cross-browser_behavior).

Comment: @jfriend00—another is to use *forEach* directly on the collection, since it will (should?) be shimmed already. ;-) IE8 is still [*around 10%*](https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0), but dropping quickly, so *nearly* there.

Comment: @Xufox - I fixed it.  Thx. In the future, you can directly propose an edit to fix that type of mistake.

Comment: @jfriend00 No need to propose an edit as I already have more than 2k reputation, but I’m not always sure when to comment and when to edit.

Comment: @Xufox - yeah, I know what you mean about it being unclear when to do one or the other.  I would have been happy with an edit in this case, since it was a clear typing mistake.